# WPF TextBlock Displaying String Over Multiple Lines

Tags: wpf, textblock

I have a string:

```
Item A\r\nItem B\r\nItem C
```

How can I bind this string to a TextBlock so that it appears as:

```
Item A
Item B
Item C
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make the `TextBlock` big enough to show three lines. `TextBlock` is capable of wrapping the text if it finds newline and carriage return in `Text`.

**EDIT:** Also, make sure that the newline and carriage returns are not hard coded. What I mean is that there is a difference between these two:

```
MyString = @"Item A\r\nItem B\r\nItem C";
```

and...

```
MyString = "Item A\r\nItem B\r\nItem C";
```

The second string will display correctly in the `TextBlock` but the first will just get displayed in a single line as "Item A\r\nItem B\r\nItem C" because the newline and carriage characters are hard coded instead of being escape characters.

You can fix that by replacing the hard coded newline and carriage characters with their escape sequences, by:

```
MyString = MyString.Replace("\\r\\n", "\r\n");
```

or preferably by:

```
MyString = MyString.Replace("\\r\\n", Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: The TextBlock is big enough but it is not processing the newline carriage return

Comment: Can you please post the xaml. And also, what is the `TextBlock` displaying? If it is displaying "Item A\r\nItem B\r\nItem C" instead, that means the newline and carriage returns are hard coded. See my updated answer.

Comment: Replacing with Environment.NewLine worked a treat...thank you